# converting nested method chaining into recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

i have a multiple node tree and i'm trying to fill the tree with specified depth (can be user input or or a constant variable). Each node will have 7 children and each children will have 7 children and so on. the problem is to add children recursively

this is how to do it using normal methods

```
MyTreeNode root = new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]);

addChildren(root);// depth1

addChildrenToChildren(root.getChildren());// depth2

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    addChildrenToChildren(root.getChildren().get(i).getChildren()); // depth3

}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        addChildrenToChildren(root.getChildren().get(i).getChildren().get(j).getChildren()); // depth4

    }
}
```

methods used

```
private static void addChildrenToChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
    for(MyTreeNode child : children){
        addChildren(child);
    }
}

private static void addChildren(MyTreeNode root) {
        root.addChildren(Arrays.asList(
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7]),
                new MyTreeNode(new int[6][7])
        ));
    }
```

what i have tried doing

```
public static void depth(MyTreeNode root, int n){
    if (n == 1){
        addChildren(root);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            addChildrenToChildren(root.getChildren());
            depth(root.getChildren().get(i), n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

myTreeNode class

```
public class MyTreeNode{
    private int[][] grid;
    private List<MyTreeNode> children = new ArrayList<MyTreeNode>();
    private MyTreeNode parent = null;

    public MyTreeNode(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public void addChild(MyTreeNode child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void addChild(int[][] grid) {
        MyTreeNode newChild = new MyTreeNode(grid);
        this.addChild(newChild);
    }

    public void addChildren(List<MyTreeNode> children) {
        for(MyTreeNode t : children) {
            t.setParent(this);
        }
        this.children.addAll(children);
    }

    public List<MyTreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public int[][] getGrid() {
        return grid;
    }

    public void setGrid(int[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    private void setParent(MyTreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public MyTreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt at recursion, `addChildrenToChildren(root.getChildren())` is executed 7 times -- this is not right. Moreover, you don't need `addChildrenToChildren`, as that will be the job of the recursive call. Instead you should call `addChildren(root);` also when `n` is greater than 1. The only difference with the base case is the loop where the recursive call is made on each child.

I would also treat the base case at `n` is 0, so that the main caller could even call it with `n` equal to 0 and get the corresponding result (no children are added then):

```
public static void depth(MyTreeNode root, int n){
    if (n <= 0) return; // Nothing to do
    addChildren(root);
    for (MyTreeNode child : root.getChildren()) {
        depth(child, n - 1);
    }
}
```